# From Datagridview to other datagridview add under older rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have little problem , I shared images and code below.

I have two datagridview in my code block. First(left side in form) datagridview's name **searchDataGridView**. This grid shows data from my database by some filters. Second(right side in form) datagridview's name **dataGridView1**. This grid shows when I click next button if I select some rows from first grid then this rows will add to dataGridView1. This code block working very well but this  that my problem when I click next button and selected rows and  added to dataGridView1 then searchDataGridVİew will show new items and selected rows will add to datagridView1, but when I add new items to dataGridView older rows will clear and new selected rows will add but I need that news selected rows must add to under older rows. Thank you for helping.

```
 private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           
            Search searchObj = new Search();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Item");
            dt.Columns.Add("Company");
            dt.Columns.Add("Category");
            dt.Columns.Add("Price");

            foreach (DataGridViewRow drv in searchDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                bool chkboxselect = Convert.ToBoolean(drv.Cells["CheckBox"].Value);             

                if (chkboxselect)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(drv.Cells[2].Value, drv.Cells[3].Value, drv.Cells[4].Value, drv.Cells[8].Value);
                    drv.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    drv.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Aqua;

                }
              
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;            
                

            }
            

            counter +=1;
            

            if (counter == maxIndex)
            {
                counter =0;
            }

            try
            {
                searchCategoryComboBox.SelectedIndex = counter;
            }


            catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)  // CS0168
            {
                MessageBox.Show("hata yakalandı");
                return;
            }

            //catch for error outofrange
           
          
            searchCategoryComboBox.SelectedIndex =counter;
            searchObj.Company = searchCompanyComboBox.Text;
            searchObj.Category = searchCategoryComboBox.Text;


            SearchManager searchMangObj = new SearchManager();
            DataTable dt2 = searchMangObj.SearchInfo(searchObj);
            searchDataGridView.DataSource = dt2;



            textBox1.Text = String.Empty;



        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okey. I erased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you get data from the db:

```
        DataTable dt2 = searchMangObj.SearchInfo(searchObj);
        searchDataGridView.DataSource = dt2;
```

Your SearchInfo method returns a new datatable and you bind that so the rows from the previous table are lost. Modify this method so it takes a datatable as a parameter (ie the existing datatable) and add rows to it.

You didn't say how your SearchInfo works to get rows from the db, but I suspect it will use a dataadapter or tableadapter, in which case you should set its `ClearBeforeFill` property to `false` to stop it from clearing the search datatable (the table that is databind'd to the searchdatagridview.DataSource)

You would then use it like:

```
searchMangObj.SearchInfo(searchDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable);
```

And it would be coded like:

```
void SearchInfo(DataTable dt){
  var dataadapter = blah blah blah;
  dataadapater.ClearBeforeFill = false;
  dataadapter.Fill(dt);
}
```